# Can a finite sequence be finite, even if it's indexed by infinite index set?

Tags: functional-analysis

Can a finite sequence be finite, even if it's indexed by infinite index set?

That is, if $\omega(k)$ is a finite sequence, but $k$ belongs to an infinite index set, then even though $\omega$ is supposed to converge, since it's a finite sequence, it wouldn't, because there's no such $k$ to display it's limit, since indices $k$ have infinite cardinality so there's no last element?

Or perhaps this means that $\omega$ would have infinite elements, but since some elements are repeated, it's range's cardinality would still be finite and thus it's a finite sequence?

---

> A finite sequence is a sequence whose limit exists and it's the last member of the sequence.

Comment: Does the word "finite" apply to the number of terms of the sequence, to the fact that the sequence is bounded, to the limit of the sequence ... your question is unclear. It would also help to know whether the elements of the sequence are real numbers (or some other kind of number or function). At the moment it is impossible to work out what you are actually asking.

Comment: @MarkBennet A finite sequence is a sequence whose limit exists and it's the last member of the sequence? My question is about, can this be true, if the indices $k$ have infinite cardinality. I.e. if $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \omega(k)$ exists, since $\omega$ is finite sequence, it doesn't exist, because one cannot display such $k$, where its limit occurs?

Comment: I would call a sequence with infinite domain but a finite range rather "eventually stationary", but not finite.

Comment: Every thing is possible in sequence’s world. See my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about $$a_{n}=1^{n}$$ this sequence has one element, when n is from 0 to infinity .

Comment: Yeah so that's exactly what I was saying about the range being finite and thus it's a finite sequence, even when its index set is infinite.

Comment: Please accept the answer, thanks

Comment: The domain is the index set, the range is finite.

Comment: @PeterMelech Yeah, sorry I was confusing you with using domain in the meaning of range, because I don't use these English terms so often.

Comment: @mavavilj No problem, but again: "eventually stationary" seems a much better term to distinguish these sequences from those with an actually finite domain, i.e. a finite index set.